# React-Native-Navigation get rid of constructor?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

In the `react-native-navigation`(not `react-navigation`) the example says

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  this.state = {
    text: 'nothing yet'
  };
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of the constructor in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially three things that are going on in your constructor - a call to the superclass constructor, a call to `Navigation.events().bindComponent`, and an initial state.

If you had no constructor, the `super` constructor would still be called, and you could move the state initialization outside, like this:

```
  state = {
    text: 'nothing yet'
  };
```

But there is no good way to call `Navigation.events().bindComponent` whenever an instance of your class is created without a constructor. So if you need to call this function, you need a constructor.